# Remove from array in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in postgres having column `web` with jsonb type. It contains values like below. I want to remove from the array. Can you please help.

Jsonb column only has values like below 2 rows

```
["test.com","test.com","abc.com"]
["google.com","fb.com","google.com"]
```

Required output

```
["test.com","abc.com"]
["google.com","fb.com"]
```

Comment: this  might help - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/226456/how-can-i-get-a-unique-array-in-postgresql

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built-in, but it's easy to write a function:

```
create function unique_elements(p_input jsonb)
  returns jsonb
as
$$
  select jsonb_agg(distinct t.element)
  from jsonb_array_elements(p_input) as t(element);
$$
language sql
immutable;
```

Then use it like this:

```
select unique_elements(web)
from the_table;
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. can you let me know what is the use of   `as t(element)` here?

Comment: @hero_star: it's a [table alias](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES)